# Objective-c No visible @interface declares the selector

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking

I have void method declared in a file called LHJSonData.h:

```
-(void)UserLogin:(NSString *)user andPassWordExists:(NSString *)password;
```

and in my LHJsonData.m file I have this line:

```
@implementation LHJSonData
```

which gives me this warning:

```
/Users/jsuske/Documents/SSiPad(Device Only)ios7/SchedulingiPadApplication/Classes/LHJSonData.m:12:17: Method definition for 'UserLogin:andPassWordExists:' not found
```

and I have this method in LHJsonData.m

```
-(void)UserLogin:(NSString *)user andPassWordExists:(NSString *)password completionHandler:(void (^)(NSArray *resultsObject, NSError *error))completionHandler
{


   NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:kIP];
   NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc]
                                         initWithRequest:request];

    [operation setCredential:[NSURLCredential credentialWithUser:[@"domain" stringByAppendingString:user]
                                                        password:password persistence:NSURLCredentialPersistenceForSession]];

    operation.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];

    [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperation:operation];

    [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

        if (completionHandler) {
            completionHandler(responseObject, nil);
        }

    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

        if (completionHandler) {
            completionHandler(nil, error);
        }

    }];

    [operation start];
}
```

I get no errors or warnings with that code.

When I call this method in another file, lets call it Login.m:

```
- (void)Login
{
    NSString *rawString = [self.idTextField text];
    NSCharacterSet *whitespace = [NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet];
    [self.idTextField setText:[rawString stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:whitespace]];
    //BOOL *isAuthenticated = [userName User:self.idTextField.text andPassWordExists:self.passwordTextField.text];

    [userName UserLogin:self.idTextField.text andPassWordExists:self.passwordTextField.text:^(id responseObject, NSError *error) {
        if (responseObject) {
            [self CustomAlert:@"You have login"];
            /*[self.idTextField removeFromSuperview];
            [self.passwordTextField removeFromSuperview];
            [self.loginButton removeFromSuperview];
            self.idTextField = nil;
            self.passwordTextField = nil;
            self.loginButton = nil;
            [self CreateMenu];*/
        }else{

            [self CustomAlert:@"Sorry Login Failed, User and/or Passsword Incorrect"];
        }
    }];
```

and I get this error:

```
ARC Semantic Issue
LHLoginController.m:240:15: No visible @interface for 'LHJSonData' declares the selector 'UserLogin:andPassWordExists::'
```

I went into Build Settings and add this to Login.m:

```
-fno-objc-arc
```

That got rid of the error, but now I get a warning and my app crashes, the warning is:

```
Semantic Issue
LHLoginController.m:240:15: Instance method '-UserLogin:andPassWordExists::' not found (return type defaults to 'id')
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: You have a completion handler on your method in your .m file. The .h and .m method declarations do not match

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare your method in your .h file just like you do in your .m file.

```
-(void)UserLogin:(NSString *)user andPassWordExists:(NSString *)password completionHandler:(void (^)(NSArray *resultsObject, NSError *error))completionHandler;
```

The .m method and .h declaration do not match.

Answer (score 1):

You should be seeing the warning/error in Xcode on this line:

```
[userName UserLogin:self.idTextField.text andPassWordExists:self.passwordTextField.text:^(id responseObject, NSError *error) {
```

You are missing a name for your third parameter, going straight from `passwordTextField.text` to `:`.  The compiler is reading that as an unnamed parameter and translating it to the selector `UserLogin:andPassWordExists::`.  Notice that it has two colons at the end rather than one.  Since you don't ever declare the selector, the error/warning is raised.

The line should look like:

```
[userName UserLogin:self.idTextField.text andPassWordExists:self.passwordTextField.text completionHandler:^(id responseObject, NSError *error) {
```

As others mentioned your method signature is different in your header than your implementation.  They need to be the same.  It is likely you got into this situation because you autocompleted a method that didn't have a completion handler and tried to fix it.

Also, make sure to turn ARC back on for that file so you don't run into memory leaks.  As you can see it wasn't really an ARC problem since both settings produced a similar warning/error.  The reason ARC refused to compile is that when it encounters an undeclared selector (in this case `UserLogin:andPassWordExists::`), it doesn't know whether or not the returned value is an object or not and it can't make a memory management decision.  Before ARC a developer could look up the undeclared method, see the return type and apply the correct action.  ARC's just stricter.